# Is there a jquery select for multiple form elements?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

i want to get back an array of all:

1. hidden inputs
2. text inputs
3. select inputs
4. checkboxes

I see [this page](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) but it seems like you have to query for checkboxes seperately

is there anyway to have one selector get everything in one array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will return what you're looking for I think...

```
$("input:hidden, input:text, select, input[type='checkbox']")
```

I'm not sure if you needed this or not as well but for text areas you'd also want to add...

```
$("textarea")
```

Comment: Might want to include `:radio`

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your goal, `$('your_form_here').serialize()` might be what you're looking for. It takes all values from a form, in order to for example submit it via AJAX.

[See the docs on `serialize()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize)

Answer (score 2):

Try these selectors:

1. All hidden `input`s: `input[type=hidden]`
2. All text `input`s: `input[type=text], input:not([type])`
3. All `select`s: `select`
4. All checkboxes: `input[type=checkbox]`

Comment: As Ryan stated below, you can use `input:text` etc. for shorter selectors, as mentiond here too http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Answer (score 1):

`$('input, select')` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

`$('input:hidden, input:text, input:checkbox, select')`